# Determing Effect of Optimization

Tags: javascript, optimization

Disclaimer: This question uses jQuery for an example, but is not about jQuery.

Is there a way to determine how the compiler optimizes a certain piece of code?

For instance, assuming `someCollection.size()` is invariant, this code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < someCollection.size(); i++) ...
```

In more recent compilers, should get optimized to something more like this:

```
var _unnamed = someCollection.size();
for (var i = 0; i < _unnamed; i++) ...
```

So writing this code yourself gives you no value (and may be less readable).

Recently, I wanted to see how using arrow functions would affect performance.  Theoretically, they could be faster than the equivalent normal function since they have less overhead (they don't bind a number of things).  I used this as a test case:

```
$('.someClass').each( (undefined, value) => { doSomething($(value)); } );
```

And an equivalent using a "normal" function:

```
$('.someClass').each( function() { doSomething($(this)); } );
```

Each method was run a few thousand times, first the arrow function and then the normal function and I was surprised to see that the arrow function was consistently slightly slower.  To be fair, I then ran the normal function first and the result was reversed, the normal function was slower.  It didn't seem to matter which function was run first - it would always be slower.  Once I started arbitrarily running one method of the function first and throwing away those results the rest of the results became very similar.

My assumption is that there is some optimization being done in the first test that is affecting the results of the subsequent tests.

My question is: How can I find out what the optimizer is doing so I can determine if any particular optimization actually has an effect?

Comment: You must be very careful when benchmarking JavaScript. What tool or approach did you use to determine your findings?

Comment: @TravisJ I'm aware.  The results will change depending on the tool - and maybe the answer to this question will also.  I'm hoping that there is some standard (i.e.  browser/context independent) way of doing this

Comment: Also why are those two function's the same. Also jquery.each, might be a bad example to test with, as the 'this' context has already be bound for you.  The arrow function is useful for when you want to keep 'this' context from contained within the callee..

Comment: @Keith `value` in the arrow function will be the same object as `this` in the "normal" function.

Comment: But it's not the same, jquery is still going to bind this, as that's what jquery does for you.  And then your using an arrow function to bind again for no reason, as now your passing the value into parameters.  The arrow function is therefore pointless.

Comment: Related: http://www.incaseofstairs.com/2015/06/es6-feature-performance/

Comment: @Keith Arrow functions do not bind `this`, it will be bound to the window.  (test it and see).

Comment: @TravisJ awesome link, thanks.  Sounds like I need to download a transpiler or two :)

Comment: () => {}  binds, to the callee's this, that's the whole point of an arrow function..  If the callee is window then it will bind to the window, but if the callee is a function it binds to that. (test it and see)

Comment: To note, arrow functions do have a thisBinding, however they simply inherit it from the LexicalEnvironment (parent scope). If the parent is window, then this is window; if the parent is an object, then this is that object.

Comment: Spot on @Travis,  and if you want to see it in action the javascript way, simply go to Babeljs.io, and click on Try it out and paste the following. ->  `function test() {this.x = 0;setTimeout(() => {console.log(this.x) });}`   Look at what (this) compiles to..

Comment: @Keith yes, `this` will remain bound to whatever is in the client's context, which is completely different to what jQuery would bind it to (which is the elements of the result of `each`).  That's the whole point.

Comment: @Tibrogargan  Yep, that's what I said..

Comment: @Keith no, you said "And then your using an arrow function to bind again for no reason", which is completely the opposite to "inherit it from the LexicalEnvironment (parent scope)"

Comment: @Tibrogargan, I said it binds this for you, I didn't day what it binded too,  Of course it's the iterators elements,.. What else would it bind too?.

Comment: And my point was, it still will be binding to 'this', using arrow function doesn't magically change jquery's code.

Comment: @Keith `this` is completely not needed by the example, it's irrelevant what it's bound to.  It's only being used in the normal function to improve readability

Answer (score 2):

> For instance, assuming `someCollection.size()` is invariant, this code:

Current JS Engines are not able to determine that `someCollection.size()` is invariant, so they are not able to perform this optimization. And this method is highly unlikely to be inlined (this would allow mentioned optimization).

You're calling a function, this function could do pretty much anything, so no certainties here at all.

> My question is: How can I find out what the optimizer is doing so I can determine if any particular optimization actually has an effect?

Currently, we have 3/4 major JS engines in the field:

- V8 in Chrome & Opera
- Chakra in Edge
- SpiderMonkey in FF
- And I'm not entirely sure what Apple's using, whether they migrated to V8, or still use Nitro.
  Anyway, in my experience, Safari's performance differs to Chrome.

You could expect that each of these basically use the same optimization techniques, but since you can experience differences in performance you can also conclude that they apply them differently.

My Conclusion here: **you're chasing a ghost / premature optimization**

Even if you'd show a distinct function it would be impossible to determine the final optimizations applied by the any of these JIT-compilers since it also depends on data collected from the particular calls of this function and the passed values. So one function may be optimized in different ways on different calls of your site, just through different usage.

Take a look at this: [Vyacheslav Egorov - LXJS 2013 - Performance and benchmarking](https://youtu.be/65-RbBwZQdU)

Not an answer to this question but maybe a few insights why this whole question (as it is) is a waste of time.

Comment: thanks for the answer.  I've already been thinking that the only differences are going to be more about readability / project structuring / style than performance.  That being said, I disagree that it's premature optimization.  If you have already determined that a piece of code really is not performing to requirements then you need a method of determining if a change is having the desired effect.  Trial and error seems like a poor choice

Comment: Did some testing myself using Chrome -> Version 53.0.2785.116..  And I'd certainly agree you'd be chasing ghosts.  One thing I did notice with chrome though, is that the Arrow functions where at first slower than straight forward binding, and the good old that=this.  But increasing the iterations made it nearly as fast as that=this. I assume turbofan kicks in.  that=this, was in all cases the fastest.  And would make sense as it's always in the local scope.

Comment: @Keith don't focus on arrow functions.  I used them as an example.  I hypothesized that they could be faster because they have lower overhead.  When I tried to test my hypothesis I discovered my testing techniques aren't adequate.  The question is regarding whether there are standard ways to improve my techniques.  Travis's suggestion of using a transpiler seems like an option - although there is perhaps a lot of variance between them

Comment: @Tibrogargan, I agree on that, just, your question feels like you're another one trying to find the "most performant" way to iterate a list. If you have performance issues I'd say, you either have a really huge bulk of data you're processing, or that you trigger render cycles that could have been avoided, or that some function that gets called all the time DEOPTs. In the 1st case: try to process the data async in multiple smaller chunks, 2nd case: maybe you can rearrange some lines to avoid unnecessarily render cycles, and 3rd. case: check the function arguments, aim for monomorphic functions

Comment: @Tibrogargan  I was only focusing on arrow functions only because you said `Recently, I wanted to see how using arrow functions would affect performance`, but if your looking into something else, no probs..

Comment: @Thomas The current problem I'm working on has an estimate of 288 days of (single threaded) processor time (approx 30M operations at ~1 second each).  Given diminishing returns of parallelism we're looking at ways to reduce the 1 second in order to get the final duration under the client's requirements.   Of course, "don't use javascript" may seem like an obvious choice.

Comment: That sounds like fun. @Tibrogargan Is there a way to take a look at this?

Comment: @Thomas not really (not without you becoming a vendor, signing an NDA, blah blah).  It's pretty boring.  Many years worth of data being migrated from one system to another.

Comment: @Tibrogargan That's too bad. Such a task, in particular, should be a matter of minutes, maybe hours, but not Months. 1s per iteration sounds like there's some structural/conceptional problem. I assume that it involves some requests to both systems, because I can't imagine that transforming a data row could take a second to complete. If that's the case, you could try to compute multiple rows in parallel, or maybe batching the requests. (to Server A: gimme the next 100 rows, ... process them, to Server B: push these 100 rows to your DB)

Comment: @Thomas 1s is low for many types of image processing, And while the old system does have structural problems in the data (and each record is quite large), the question is more about "If I needed to do something like this in Javascript, what techniques can I use to verify that a change I made actually had the effect that I think it did?".  Imagine you're writing a game in JS/CSS/whatever.  You put a lot of objects on screen for your final battle and it starts chugging, despite fixing rendering issues.  Trial and error will work, but concrete techniques are better.

Comment: @Tibrogargan, OK, didn't associate image processing with data migration. To your question: Chrome -> Dev-tools -> timeline and Profile. There you can get the metrics to determine wether performance has improved. Or to determine wich functions are the hot ones (consume most time). As mentioned, search for deoptimized functions, try to determine why it get's deoptimized, and "fix it".